# How to configure target of sitecore link to "Custom"

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-dms, sitecore7.2

Sitecore provides an option to set the target of a Link item to "Custom". If the user selects the target as "custom" then he has to provide the target window details in the custom textbox. So Could you please help me how to configure that custom window in sitecore?

Comment: Sitecore is a document management system, not a development tool. This question appears to be better suited to superuser.com.

Comment: Are you talking about an external link?

Answer (score 1):

I think the custom textbox will take framename as value. If you are using frameset on your target page you can give the framename in the custom textbox.

Note: frame tag is not supported in HTML5.